# How to inspect elements in a desktop application?

Tags: desktop-application, node-webkit

I am from the web-development world, not knowing anything about desktop apps. The app is developed using coffee script and packaged through node-webkit. I wanted to know, if there is a way by which I can inspect the elements in the app. 
While googling I came through [Adobe AIR](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WSfffb011ac560372f20b57e08128cc91aa2f-7ffe.html) and [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com/).
But nothing seemed available for just a node-webkit app. Does anyone have any idea on the same??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm the developer of the [Spark Inspector](http://www.sparkinspector.com/) tool you mentioned.

I've done a fair bit of development in Node and I think you might enjoy the Firebug inspector for Firefox, or the Chrome Inspector built into Chrome (https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/). Both of these need your page to be open in the browser, but if your app is web-based and you can pop it into a standard browser window, you're in luck. (If not, it might be worthwhile making it work in a standard browser—even if it'll end up packaged into an app—so you can debug it!)

Hope that helps,

Answer (score 5):

Use the developer tools built into node-webkit.

In your package.json set "toolbar": true this will show the "cog" icon which displays chrome dev tools for your app.

Comment: But it does not allow you to pin point a dom element from your mouse and inspect element on it, instead you have to go through the whole DOM tree which I find tedious. Anyone knows how to use to Menu API in nodewebkit to trigger the inspector on the active element like in Google chrome/Chromium/Safari?

Comment: @AsadHasan There is a lens icon at bottom left corner to pin point and inspect.